# how to know in which directory a sudo user is working if i am a root user

Tags: linux

Is there any way by which I can get which sudo user working in which directory on which file.

Is there any file which shows details of current working directory of all sudo user.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `pgrep sudo` to get all sudo processes, then `ps h --ppid $THEPID -o pid` to get its child processes and finally `pwdx $SUBPID` to get the working directory of these subprocesses.

You could finally sum it up in two for loops, which could look like this:

```
for sudo in `pgrep sudo`; do
 sudo pwdx $sudo;
 for subsudo in `ps h --ppid $sudo -o pid`; do
   sudo pwdx $subsudo
 done
done
```

Because you get only one generation of child processes with each call of `ps`, the process numbers of child processes must be obtained recursively.
The following script does this:

```
#!/bin/bash

function getchildren()
{
  echo $1
  children=`ps h --ppid $1 -o pid`
  if [[ -n $children ]]; then
   for child in $children; do
     getchildren $child
   done
  fi
}


for sudo in `pgrep sudo`; do
 for subsudo in `getchildren $sudo`; do
   sudo pwdx $subsudo
 done
done | sort | uniq
```

The output is sorted and double lines are removed in case someone runs a `sudo` process from within a `sudo su` session.